# Android phone won't receive SNS push notifications

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I have a few Android phones.  I'm pushing messages to them via Amazon SNS to GCM, using boto in Python.  One phone always receives the messages.  The other one does not.

The first time I send a message to the problem phone, it appears to succeed but nothing goes through.  When I go to the AWS console and look at the list of endpoints registered to my app, it now shows "false" under the Enabled column.

The second time I send a message, boto raises an exception with a message in it: "Endpoint is Disabled"

What are some reasons why an android phone would not receive GCM messages?  Are there user settings that can disable this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you figured it out, however, I post the answer for future use. [This is](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx223MJB0XKV9RU/Mobile-token-management-with-Amazon-SNS) a good article around this topic and addresses some possibilities about the problem.

Based on your explanation I think the Token for the android phone is expired and it needs to get re-registered with the GCM, then the SNS endpoint should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Token may have expired, or it may have been cleared from the app's storage. On your Android app, create a class that extends FirebaseInstanceIdService and override this function:

```
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
    // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
    // Instance ID token to your app server.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}
```

Also create your own sendRegistrationToServer. On your backend, implement a function that receives the token and assigns it to that endpoint's ARN. This way, your backend will always know where to send the notification.